# Set Documents library as the Home view in Sharepoint 365?

Tags: sharepoint

The homepage for my Sharepoint site is a view that includes the Documents library. This view looks nearly identical to the actual Documents library, but is missing most of the controls. Users have to click in the navigation bar to select Documents to access the full functionality of that library.

This is confusing. We only use SP for documents. Is there some way to make the documents library the site's default page?

This is the URL for the "Documents" link:

/sites/Team/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

This is the URL for the "Home" link:

/sites/Team

The only page listed in the "Pages" view is Home.aspx. There's nothing I can select for the documents library to "Make Homepage".

[Documents view showing limited controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJRKC.png)

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me;
[How to make a document library the default site homepage](https://itsupport.smu.edu.sg/hc/en-us/articles/360033229674--Customisation-How-to-make-a-document-library-the-default-site-homepage)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking for this and finds this, as of 10-25-22, this is how you can set the documents page to the home page for a site:

Use this clickpath: [gear] -> Site Contents -> Site Settings -> Site Collection Features -> Sharepoint Lists and Libraries experience -> Activate.

Then click the Sharepoint Site icon in the upper left of the page (The logo/icon immediately to the left of the words "Site Settings > Site Collection Features")

From this page, select your Documents Page.  Then [gear icon] > Edit page.  Click the "Page" tab at the top > Make Homepage.  Click "OK" to the warning for overwriting the existing homepage.  Click "Stop Editing".

Re-enable the new view by reversing (Deactivate) the "Sharepoint Lists and Libraries experience" in the clickpath above.

Hopefully this helps someone out!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the feature "Publishing Infrastructure" at sitecollection level. Then turn "Publishing" on at site level.

Once these are turn on go to "Site Actions > Site Settings > Look and Feel". You will get a new option called "Welcome Page". You need to paste the url you want as the new site landing page.

Comment: Thank you. I used this clickpath to enable the Welcome Page link: [gear] -> Site Contents -> Site Settings -> Manage site Features -> Sharepoint Server Publishing -> Activate. Enabling this at the site collection level did not work. Unfortunately, the page rejects setting anything in the Form folder as a welcome page. Perhaps this isn't possible with a Teams Sharepoint site?